# CSS Media queries gets overriden when lightbox is open

Tags: css, colorbox, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a CSS media query overwriting an element when the screen is smaller than 1000px. The media query works well until I open a colorbox, at that time the media query gets overridden by previous styles.

My code is this:

master.css

```
#header .holder {
...
width: 960px;
...
}
```

mobile.css

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 320px) {
  #header .holder {
  ...
  width: 100%;
  ...
  }
}
```

When I open a colorbox I get this in Chrome's CSS inspector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvkUr.png
(previous styles are overriding media queries' ones)

Why does the code gets overridden? What event is colorbox triggering in the window to make this happen?

Comment: What order are your CSS files? It may be that because even a narrow browser satisfies the main width, so it's not needing to apply the mobile version. Try putting the mobile.css last so it's the last thing rendered?

Comment: What do you mean by 'colorbox' ?

Comment: It seems from your screenshot that the previous styles are coming from a `master.php`, which would make it an internal style sheet. Since it has the same selector specificity as your external style sheet, could it be that the previous style is being used because the internal style sheet has greater priority?

Comment: Guys, it had nothing to do with css files order, let me explain: master.php is a css compiler serving CSS content, is interpreted as CSS. master.php is loaded first the mobile.css

Thanks for your help, Jack had the right answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of colorbox here.  I haven't heard of an issue with this before, but it could be the result of the content you are displaying in colorbox.

Weird problems like this are typically due to people improperly opening HTML documents as ajax, rather than displaying them in an iframe.  The resulting mix of invalid HTML, scripts, and styles cause all sorts of issues.

My guess is that this is something specific to your implementation.  I suggest trying to create a simplified demostration of the problem in jsfiddle.net and posting a link to that here, or to colorbox's issue tracker.

Comment: Yep Jack, that made it, that was the problem: I was opening my colorbox window as ajax, the document loaded was overwriting the styles in parent document. This is such a n0ob mistake, thanks for your help.